# Only load Views Slideshow JavaScript when needed

Tags: 7, views, javascript

Does anyone know how to only load the Views Slideshow JavaScript on certain content-types, pages, or the front page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to only enable a Views Slideshow (or any other object) on certain pages, I recommend having Views output a block and then setting that block to display only on the necessary pages. It should only call the js (which should reside in sites/all/libraries) on pages that load the block. You can then set the block to display or hide by role, page, etc.